# Date Conversion Difference Between Python Datetime and Excel

Tags: python, excel, datetime, xlrd

I’m trying to parse data that I’ve received from an excel file in Python. For this I am using the `xlrd` library. I have a cell in Excel whose value is 5/16/2016 12:15 and I receive it in Python as 42506.6493. I understand that Excel saves the date as the number of days since 1/1/1900. So in Python I’m trying to add this number of days (just days for now without the fraction representing the time) to get the same date, using the code below:

```
orgDate = datetime.datetime(1900,1,1,0,0,0,0)
xlVal = 42506.6493
newDate = orgDate + datetime.timedelta(days=int(xlVal))
```

However when I read the value of `newDate` I find it to be `datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 18, 0, 0)` whereas it should be May 16 not 18. Anybody knows how to handle this?

Comment: I'm not a python developer, but does not int() round the value to a full digit? So your fraction ".6493" is rounded up to "+1", which means 42506 becomes 42507?

Comment: If I'm correct with the above, then there is one day diff. That could perhaps be because day 0 in excel is day 1 in python? So 1900-01-01 12:00 is in excel "0.5", but in python datetime "1.5"?

Comment: Hello Andreas. No, int(x.y) returns x. There is also a two-day difference (18 -> 16)

Comment: What do you get if you set `xlVal = 1` or 2? Do you get the correct date then? (Meaning in 1900)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consult the xlrd [documentation](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), particularly the section on [dates in Excel](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html).

Dates don't really start at 1900-01-01. You have a two-day difference because (1) Excel preserves the Lotus 1-2-3 bug which considers 1900 a leap year and (2) even if dates did start at 1900-01-01, then that would make 1900-01-01 day 1, not day 0, so you would need to adjust your timedelta accordingly.

But really, just save yourself the trouble and use xlrd's built-in date facilities, [`xldate_as_tuple`](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_tuple) or [`xldate_as_datetime`](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime).

Comment: Yeah I ended up using `xldate_au_tuple` in the end. But still, your explanation is very helpful. Thanks a lot I’ll give you best answer!