# Format 'Python datetime' and 'excel date number' in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, datetime

My DataFrame 'Expense_Date' has following values -

| Index | Expense_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-20 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-01-17 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 45023 |
| 4 | 45047 |
| 5 | 2021-01-15 00:00:00 |

I want to format 'Expense_Date' column to Python Datetime format.

I tried below, but not working. please help -

```
def Format_dates(date_value) -> datetime:
    import datetime as dt
    try:
        delta = [dt.datetime(1899,12,30) + pd.Timedelta(days=ts.astype(int)) for ts in date_value]
    except:
        delta = date_value.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
    finally:
        return delta

Formatted_Date = pd.Series(Format_dates(df['Expense_Date']))
```

try block is not executing at all.

I also tried below solution but not working as my DataFrame has both Dates as well as number
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478748/date-conversion-difference-between-python-datetime-and-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Expense_Date': ['2022-07-20 00:00:00', '2023-01-17 00:00:00', '45023', '45047', '2021-01-15 00:00:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

`df`

```
    Expense_Date
0   2022-07-20 00:00:00
1   2023-01-17 00:00:00
2   45023
3   45047
4   2021-01-15 00:00:00
```

**Code**

Convert values to NaNs if they are not numeric, then convert them to dates, and then replace the NaNs with the original dates.

```
s = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_numeric(df['Expense_Date'], errors='coerce'), unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')
pd.to_datetime(s.fillna(df['Expense_Date']))
```

output:

```
0   2022-07-20
1   2023-01-17
2   2023-04-07
3   2023-05-01
4   2021-01-15
Name: Expense_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If you want to change the date format to '%m/%d/%Y', you can use dt.strftime on the above result.

```
pd.to_datetime(s.fillna(df['Expense_Date'])).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

output:

```
0    07/20/2022
1    01/17/2023
2    04/07/2023
3    05/01/2023
4    01/15/2021
Name: Expense_Date, dtype: object
```

---

**intermediate**

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Expense_Date'], errors='coerce')
```

output:

```
0        NaN
1        NaN
2    45023.0
3    45047.0
4        NaN
Name: Expense_Date, dtype: float64
```